# How to prevent cell tower switching and data cut off

Tags: data-connection

Samsung Galaxy S4 here. I found that my phone often switches cell towers through an app called GSM signal monitoring. I don't know if this is the phone's fault or not, but the most annoying thing about it is that when the switching happens any and all data transfer are completely interrupted and stopped, and are unable to resume even after the switching is done. This happens whether I'm mobile in a car or stationary sitting on my desk. I could be downloading 100 KBps and just completely stop and I have to restart the download all over again. Is there a way to stop this from happening? Maybe lower the tolerance on which the decision to switch is made?

Comment: What you're asking for is beyond the scope of this site? There could be masts nearby "competing" with each other, or the telephony layer determines that the signal is weak and switches to another to "strengthen" or even "roaming" around different areas and that causes the interrupted downloads. Really, downloading at 100KBps over 3G is not a good idea either for that especially if in a poor reception area.

Comment: Not really sure why it's beyond the scope of this site. Was wondering if there's an app or something to do that. Obviously I can't control how fast I'm downloading at any given point. I don't want the phone to switch towers while i'm stationary. It doesn't really make any sense to me. I'm sitting at the same place and having a good connection, why interrupt it? It makes an unreliable experience.

Comment: OP: this is network/carrier related and hence beyond scope of this site as there is no direct control over that nor preventing it from happening :)

Comment: I see. Well i guess my real question is IS there a way to programmatically control this behavior. I guess by your answer there is not. Is this a behavior that is encountered on all device and all carriers then?

Comment: No way to control that programmatically sorry! That is the telephony layer's function *read - chipset* and network/carrier related.